# Does an AWS S3 session expire?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I have a service that downloads files from an s3 bucket.

For that I need a `*session.Session`.

I see myself with two options.

### Option 1

```
type S3Client struct {
    session *session.Session
}

func NewS3Client(region string) (*S3Client, error) {
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String(region)})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &S3Client{
        session: sess,
    }, nil
}
```

Then I may use the client to download stuff with given session.

### Option 2

Open a new session every time I need to download a file.

```
func DownloadFromS3(region, bucket, file string) (string, error) {
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String(region)})
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // download using the session
```

---

Question: is **option 1** viable or is there a sort of expiration mechanism on the session ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name `session` is misleading. It is replaced with a simplified configuration system provided by the [config](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config) package in AWS SDK for Go V2. See [Configuration Loading](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/migrating/#configuration-loading).

[The document for the session package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/session/) explicitly states that sessions should be cached if possible:

> Package session provides configuration for the SDK's service clients. Sessions can be shared across service clients that share the same base configuration.
>
> Sessions are safe to use concurrently as long as the Session is not being modified. **Sessions should be cached when possible, because creating a new Session will load all configuration values from the environment, and config files each time the Session is created**. Sharing the Session value across all of your service clients will ensure the configuration is loaded the fewest number of times possible.

Comment: From my understanding then, option 1 is perfectly viable in a webserver environment when I would from time to time download file from S3. Right?

Comment: Yes. The name is misleading. There is nothing expired. But the configuration could be outdated though. Maybe you should plan for configuration changes.